# TemplateResponse doesn't render?

Tags: django, pjax

i just switched to TemplateResponse for using pjax. It now renders the layout correctly, but the content isn't rendered at all. even with django-pjax disabled. my view code:

```
def product(request, slug):
  product = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug)
  return TemplateResponse(request, "layouts/base.html", ({ 'product':product, 'url':request.get_full_path }))
```

in my layout i have this block:

```
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
```

and my template:

```
{% extends "layouts/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
...
{% endblock %}
```

using the normal `render-shortcut` django provides, it works right away. any advice? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

In your view, you are using the `base.html` template ...

```
return TemplateResponse(request, "layouts/base.html", ....
```

As expected, it doesn't have any content.

You would want to change it to your derived template.

Comment: oh well, i'm an idiot. just chose the wrong template... thanks!